# Bootstrap Navbar not working on mobile

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>马面的青春部落格</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--为了确保适当的绘制和触屏缩放，需要在 <head> 之中添加 viewport 元数据标签。-->
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">   <!--插入bootstarp-->
    <link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--引入js文件-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">马面的青春部落格</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="Blog.html">文章</a></li>
                <li><a href="Photo.html">相册</a></li>
                <li><a href="Person.html">个人简介</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">联系方式</a></li>
                <li><img class="navimg" src="image/twitter.png" ></li>   
                <li><img class="navimg" src="image/Github.png" ></li>
                <li><img class="navimg" src="image/gmail.png" ></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

</nav>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Example:markmamian.github.io The navbar is not working on mobile.

Comment: Try to update your question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The code for a full responsive navbar from the bootstrap website. If you are going to remove parts from it please refresh after each step to see where you are going wrong.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the basic structure to built the giant website

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/